# Application-defined or objected-defined error only shows with If Vlookup Statement

Tags: excel, vba

So i'm running into a problem with my script which fills down a formula to the last row of a column. It works for the most part except when it steps into my if function.

```
Sub vlookups()
'
' vlookups Macro
'

'
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2,'Refined Raw'!$A:$AH,2,false)"
    Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2,'Refined Raw'!$A:$AH,3,false)"
    Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2,'Refined Raw'!$A:$AH,4,false)"
    Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2,'Refined Raw'!$A:$AH,5,false)"
    Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP($A2,'Refined Raw'!$A:$AH,6,false)=0,'',VLOOKUP($A2,'Refined Raw'!$A:$AH,6,false))"


End Sub
```

This runs fine on the first 4 Range vlookups, however when it hits the last one with the IF(VLOOKUP it shows an error. I'm not too well versed with VBA so i'm not sure what could be causing this issue.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double up on the quotes inside a formula:

```
 "=IF(VLOOKUP($A2,'Refined Raw'!$A:$AH,6,false)=0,"""",VLOOKUP($A2,'Refined Raw'!$A:$AH,6,false))"
```

Comment: this worked, thanks! curious, why did it need double quotes?

Comment: @DannyMoncadea - Note how you start the `.Formula` with `"=IF(...`. When you do a single quote, VBA interprets that as the end of the statement.  By doubling quotes, it resolves that to `""` when the formula is inserted. ...if that makes sense.